# Периодическая очистка БД SQLite C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, task

Посоветуйте.
Имею приложение с БД SQLite, в БД хранятся события. Хочу добавить в приложение настройку, сколько дней хранить события.
Приложение подразумевает работу 24/7.
Достаточно просто Task'а с циклом while(true) c Task.Delay(timeout)?
Т.е. с какой то периодичностью (какой?) цикл повторяется и вычисляет разницу во времени от сегодня (или от самого свежего события?) до последнего события в БД. Если разница больше настройки, то старые события удаляются.

Comment: Так в чем проблема? Ставьте в событиях отметку времени и удаляйте записи старше определенного срока.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Проблемы нет. Возможно есть общепринятый способ, который я не знаю. Предположил с циклом while.

Comment: Общепринято ставить в событиях отметку времени, ессвено чтобы было удобней видеть когда произошло событие. Надеюсь, у вас отметки времени ставятся? Вот по ним и отсекайте старые записи. Как вы это сделаете: внешней утилитой запускаемой по расписанию или прямо в программе - не важно, вопрос только как вам больше удобней.

Comment: @ГеннадийП да, отметки времени есть. Пока реализую так, как описал выше.

Comment: Можно использовать триггер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никакие таски не нужны. Достаточно сразу после внесения новой записи, тут же удалять запись с требуемым условием.

Допустим, у вас условие хранить запись только в течении 2-х дней. Когда вы вносите новую запись датированную `26.09.2018 10:00`, то в след за этим находите все записи старше `24.09.2018 10:01` и удаляете их.

Comment: точно, отличное решение!

Comment: Пожалуйста.. :)